# make da( or dab remove lagging whitespace like daw

Tags: cut-copy-paste, cursor-motions, object-motions

**TL;DR**: `da(` doesn't delete the following space like `daw` does. Can I make this do what I want easily?

I have some sample lines (cursor is shown as `|`):

```
1. Sample line (extraneous| statement) in notes.
2. Sample line extra|neous in notes.
```

On line 2, `daw` will leave me with a complete, well-written sentence: `Sample line in notes.`

On line 1, `da(` will leave extra spaces: `Sample line  in notes.`, which is undesirable.

I know I could make a completely custom bind that does `da(dl` to avoid this issue, but I would like to use `da(` rather than some new key combination, and I don't know how I could remap that. I read `motion.txt` in `:help` and it looks like this isn't possible, but I figured I could be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to remap `a(`—

```
onoremap a( :<C-u>normal! va(l<CR>
```

This should make all uses of it include the space.

Comment: `da(` with your remap on `My (parenthetical st|atement) sentence` yields `My )| sentence`.

Comment: @jeremysprofile good catch;  I forgot that the rhs is not executed in normal mode! Try the edit

Comment: Perfect! I prefer the individual remap to a full plugin, so this is ideal for me. Note to others that you will have to remap each wrap (`a[`, `a{`, `a"`, etc) if you need this behavior for other wrappings.

Answer (score 2):

Plug-in [wellle/targets.vim](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim) includes an operator mapping for this specific situation. The mapping is `A(` or `Ab`, which is analogous to `a(` but includes the whitespace following the pair.

See the plug-in's documentation for the ["Around Pair"](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim#around-pair) operator.